# Unable create layout with image and text for listvieitem

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dip"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rowcontact_txtName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:text="Usama Sadiq"
            android:textColor="#3a3838"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rowcontact_imgLocationIcon"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rowcontact_txtName"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rowcontact_txtLocation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rowcontact_txtName"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rowcontact_imgLocationIcon"
            android:text="Dubai"
            android:textColor="#898788"
            android:textSize="11.5dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rowcontact_imgIcon"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/rowcontact_txtLocation"
            android:layout_marginLeft="94dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rowcontact_txtName" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

i am trying to create layout for list-view item but i am not able to fix position of image and text with three different Position please tell me solution how to fix it. i have to create listviow item i am able to display list-view but like given screen 
 i have all icon an all but am unable to fix potion[image] of text-view and image view like given screen

Comment: this is called coustem listview in android

Comment: yes can u please suggest fix it like given screen

Comment: i should suggest that you should use linear layout for this custom list view. so that your components will be fixed at position.

Comment: @user2794306    ok i will make and post please confirm only post listview Row

Comment: yes only listview row i  need like given screen i need single row so that i can integarte wid listview

Comment: you want to view like this http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
       >
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rowcontact_txtName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="Usama Sadiq"
        android:textColor="#3a3838"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rowcontact_txtLocation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rowcontact_txtName"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rowcontact_imgLocationIcon"
        android:text="Dubai"
        android:textColor="#898788"
        android:textSize="11.5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </LinearLayout>

   </LinearLayout>

  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: But we have 2 textview below image view also plz check that in screen i am unable to set that text view